# Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this error when i am exporting modules from file A and importing in file B and when i am running file B it gives that error.that is related to Firebase cloud Firestore.

```
const mailEvents = (startTime, endTime) => {

  serverRef = db.collection("MailEvents");
  let getDocs = serverRef
    .where("timestamp", ">=", startTime)
    .where("timestamp", "<=", endTime)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      if (querySnapshot) {
        let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        console.log(docs)
      }
    });
}
mailEvents();
module.exports.mailEvents = mailEvents;
```

and the main.js file is

```
const module = require('./report.js')

module.mailEvents(1575225929,1575305012);
```

Comment: Your first bit of code is showing a function called "mailEvents", but your second bit of code is calling a function called "mailEventReports".  They don't match.  Please edit the question with the correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your module, right before the export, you call the `mailEvents()` function without any arguments, hence the error "Cannot used "undefined" as a Firestore value" because it's trying to query the collection with `startTime` and `endTime` as undefined. In other words, each time you require this file, you're essentially calling the method twice. You can also simplify a few lines here. It should work if you change that file to this:

```
const mailEvents = (startTime, endTime) => {
    db.collection("MailEvents")
        .where("timestamp", ">=", startTime)
        .where("timestamp", "<=", endTime)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            if (querySnapshot && querySnapshot.length > 0) {
                let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
                console.log(docs)
            }
        });
};

module.exports = {
    mailEvents
};
```